# Fixed string length adding spaces and deleting exceeding char

Tags: java, string, substring

**Context:**

I wish to have a fixed string lenght since I'm formatting an output file, I built 2 functions that should be applied to string based on my string length.

1. *First function*: if you want a string X char long, but you got one which is X-Y, this adds spaces 'till desired length is reached, in this particular case, Y. This seems correct, it works

```
  public String formatSpace(String s, int desiredlength){
    while (s.length()<desiredlength){
      s+=" ";
    }
    return s;
  }
```

2. *Second function*: if you want a string X char long but you got one which is X+Y, this "removes" char until desired length is reached, in this particular case, Y. This seems to be wrong.

```
  public String truncString(String s, int desiredlength){
    return s.substr(0,s.length()-desiredlenght);
  }
```

---

**Error:**

I apply these two based on string length that I test in another part of code:

```
[...]//here i built my class
int maxlen = 60;
    [...] //here there is more code but it just collects data and I already tested fields
        if (field.length()<maxlen){
          field = formatSpace(field,maxlen);
        }else if (field.length()>maxlen){
          field = truncString(field,maxlen);
        }
[...] //here i put string on file
```

Error I get is about string index being negative, I don't know why, I tried code on paper (yes, I know it's dumb) but it works there

Why second function is not working?
Also, it would be better to make one function which format my string, how should I make it?

---

**Solution:**

Thanks to everyone who commented, I solved my problem with this single function I wrote, I don't even test string anymore, if they fit my length they're ok, else I format them:

```
  private String formatString(String s, int length) {
    while (s.length() < length) {
      s += " ";
    }
    return s.substring(0, length);
  }
```

Comment: Give exact exception and the String used

Comment: string I used is = "IWannaAbsolutelytryToSeeWhatHappensIfMyMethodNameIsThisLongggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg" 

Stack trace is:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 59

I don't know why it does fail to be honest, no clue

Comment: Your solution seems quite good tbh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use something like:

```
private static String spaces(int width) {
    // May be more efficient ways of doing this.
    return String.join("", Collections.nCopies(width, " "));
}

private static String fixedWidth(String s, int width, boolean padLeft) {
    String spaces = spaces(Math.max(0,width-s.length()));
    return (padLeft ? spaces + s : s + spaces).substring(0, width);
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    String[] tests = {"Hello", "Loooooooooooooong!!!"};
    for ( String t: tests) {
        System.out.println(fixedWidth(t,10,false));
        System.out.println(fixedWidth(t,10,true));
    }
}
```

Comment: Feels like too complex, I'm a very beginner tbh. I will surely study this code, thanks for suggestion! (I will try, if it solves my problem I will use it but I won't go on until I understand exactely how it works).

Comment: @Phyxil - The concept here is to add a string containing enough spaces either to the left or to the right of your string and then use `substring` to truncate. This then handles strings too long as well as too short.

Comment: String.join and Collections.nCopies are new to me, Math.max is intuible and I understood that, I just need to read a bit of documentation now

Comment: @Phyxil - That method just creates a string of spaces of the required length. You could just as easily use `static final String spaces = "..........";` except use spaces instead of dots (SO seems to remove multiple spaces in comments).

Comment: I solved my problem, see edit, I couldn't use .join at school because we have java 6, I think that's java 8 (I got java 8 at home)

Answer (score 1):

Second argument in `substring` function is the length of your new String. Why do you have a substraction ?
This should work :

```
 public String truncString(String s, int desiredlength){
    return s.substr(0,desiredlenght);
  }
```

Comment: Sure, but the `if` condition should prevent to throw an index error, not solve now

Comment: First of all, thank you for replying, I tried your code, but I get StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range
same error

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the second function is a logic problem. Imagine you're desired length is 4 and you introduce a String which length is 6. If you do the String length - desired length you're going to obtain a String which length is 2.

A way to fix this problem is to return directly the substr: `return s.substr(0,desiredLenght)`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this approach for a simple one line solution.

```
String test="type something here";
int desiredLength=15;

System.out.println(String.format("%1$-"+desiredLength+"s",  test.substring(0, desiredLength)));
```

The idea is => substring first to the desired length (this will happen if string is longer) and then use String format to fill to desired length with spaces ( %1$-10s is the format for left aligned string filled to 10 spaces).

Comment: I cannot use String.format, my java is 1.4 I think that's java 1.5 

I cannot upgrade, it's school PC but I'll try at home

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. Inside truncString you write desiredlenght instead of desiredlength.

Comment: It's just a typo here, in code is correct I wrote function here not copy-pasted, it's a struggle to be dyslexic